# Hide parent menu and display sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a menu page is  loaded hide the parent menu and display only the sub menu with checkboxes.

i have tried this but it is not hiding parent menu

```
          $('li').on('click', function(e) {
          $(this).children('ul').toggle();
          $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide();
          e.stopPropagation();
        });
```

Comment: include a screenshot as well so it'll be easier to picture out what  you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

try [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
 $('li').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).children('ul').toggle();
    $(this).closest( "ul" ).hide();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```